# Issue with selecting fields from database table when they are same as SQL keyword in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, websphere, ibm-midrange

I have a DB2 table with "union" as the column name.
How do I select this column on a select statement when it is same as a SQL keyword?
I tried using select [union] from table but it didn't work.

Comment: Use double quotes.

Comment: SELECT "UNION" FROM TABLE not SELECT "union" FROM TABLE

Comment: it depends on the actual name. "THEnAmE-as-IN_the-CataLOG"

Comment: Square brackets are for MS SQL Server. The DB2 way is double quotes, which is ANSI/ISO SQL!

Answer (score 2):

@user2914171 answered correctly in the comments.

```
SELECT "UNION" FROM TABLE
```

not

```
SELECT "union" FROM TABLE
```

Note that "UNION" must be upper case, or more correctly, the case specified in SYSCOLUMNS, but as long as the create table did not use quotes, or the table was defined using DDS, DB2 for i defaults to all upper case.

You can find the true case of the field name by:

```
select column_name 
from qsys2.syscolumns 
where table_name = 'TABLE' 
  and table_schema = 'LIBRARY'
```

Comment: was not aware db2 allows mixed case column names. That would help a lot when returning a result set to the browser. Mixed case column names are the norm in javascript.

Comment: Without the double quotes, DB2 (for i) translates all names to upper case before using them or storing them in the catalog. If you want other than upper case in the catalog, you must always use the double quotes.